# Does O(1) time complexity equals to O(1^n)

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

I know the definitions of both of them, but can i ignore from the O(1^n) or it's different?

Thanks.

Comment: Please share your definition of `O(1^n)`.

Comment: @TimothyGroote - Care to explain the difference?

Comment: @TimothyGroote I dont see how your first link gets to "they are different". It is 1 vs 1 power n.

Comment: misread that for O(log n). maybe i should get some sleep. sorry.

Answer (score 4):

`O(1)` means: it takes **constant** time to "do that thing", independent of any *n* you are processing.

And `1^n` computes to `1`, too. Because `1^n` is `1*1*1..` *n* times.

Maybe, maybe, if you were instead thinking about:

```
1 + 1 + 1 + 1 ... n times
```

Here you end up with `O(n)` ( 1*1*... isn't the same as 1+1+1... )

The difference is essentially: as long as the execution time is *constant*, no matter how many "things" get processed, then you are `O(1)`. As soon as that number *n* somehow comes into play, you are not.